# Sculpture UV & Paint Issue

Tags: uv, texture-painting, sculpting

I'll start this off by saying I'm new to this. I've tried to look this up, but I can't seem to figure out exactly what the problem is.

So, I made a sculpture watching a tutorial, and it turned out pretty cool! Being excited, I was hoping to try and paint some colors onto it. However, when I go to the UV Editor or the Texture Paint, only a couple of small patches are allowing the selection.

It has a high level of detail, but I'm not sure if that could be the issue. There's two patches on top and one underneath. Everything I have found thus far seems to either see all or nothing.

I'm sure this is something that I probably messed up to trying to move forward too quickly, but I appreciate any help in advance!

Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to performe a retopology, after that unwrap your Uv's and then you will be ready to paint. Start Here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hEHtKH55Us  good luck

Comment: @Emir Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to quickly do the shading without the need of retopology and UV unwraping if are not going to animate the model. You can use the texture cordinate node to change the cordination from UV to project or other ways... then using some procedural or seemles textures and mix them together with a balck and white mask as a factor instead of texture painting. Highly recommend to watch the "Materials Made Easy - Non Destructive Shading in Blender" by Zacarist Reinhardt in Blender's YouTube channel from Blender Con 2018. (Sorry having internet problem I couldn't get you a link)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not planning on getting into animation yet so this should be a good way to go. I appreciate it!